# firebase remove ID on database when click button

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm doing order shop project and in order list page work with realtime database in firebase when people order and add to database, order will update to table of orderlist like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFiry.png
and at deleted button I want to when cook finished food, click this button and order food will remove from database. But I have no idea to remove value from database with generated id. Please Help!
table script:

```
<label>Your Order:</label>
        <table class="table table-dark table-striped">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Order's List</th>
                <th>options</th>
                <th>delete</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="orderlist" class = "table=success">
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

script:

```
<script>

      let myFirebase = firebase.database();
      let dataRef = myFirebase.ref('/orders');

      function deleteRow(r) {

}

      dataRef.limitToLast(5).on('child_added', function(childSnapshot) {
      let item = childSnapshot.val()
      document.getElementById('orderlist').innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + item.student + "</td><td>" + item.food + "</td><td>" + item.options + "</td><td>" + "<button onclick=deleteRow(this)>"+"delete"+"</button></td></tr>"
});
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the function to the following:

```
<button onclick=deleteRow(this,'"+ item.student + "')>
```

Then you can do the following:

```
function deleteRow(elem, student){
  let myFirebase = firebase.database();
  let dataRef = myFirebase.ref('/orders');
    dataRef.orderByChild("name").equalTo(student).on('value', function(snapshot){
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        let key = childSnapshot.key;
        dataRef.child(key).delete(); 
          });
    });
}
```

Here first add the variable `item.student` to onclick, and then using a query you can retrieve the `key` for this specific `student` and delete it using the method `delete()`. You need to have the following database:

```
orders
   pushKey
      name      : "62070228"
      orderList : "Noodles"
      options   : "no vegetables"
```

Comment: Thank for ans, but I found problem when I doing this code: https://i.imgur.com/eBs2ovA.png because I use innerHTML to create table, so item.student will can't define when onclick button.  How to solve this problem?